# Protect my application from CSRF attacks with Spring Boot 2.6.X and JDK 1.11.XX in a persistent login application

Tags: spring-security, csrf

I have 4 questions and an unsolvable problem. In the code I have added question marks to highlight the problem.

I developed my application in Spring Boot 2 starting from an old example in Spring Boot 2.0.X and Java 1.8.X. I now use Spring Boot 2.6.X and Java 1.11.XX (currently 2.6.5 and 1.11.13). In the html pages I add this line of code:

```html
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}">
```

In java I add:

```java
http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    //http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository());
```

**I can log in but cannot log out.**

With Spring Boot 2.0.X I didn't protect the WebApp and I used:

```java
    http.csrf().disable();
```

**1)** Why does this happen? How do I resolve?

**2)** Is the method I use to make the browser remember the user's password correct or is it necessary to do it some other way with Spring Boot 2.6.X?

**3)** If you have any other advice on how to modernize my application, make it more secure I am very happy to hear from you.

Thank you

**A) ConfigurazioneSpringSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**

```java
    // 3) ?????????????
    // Configurazione di Spring Security.
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class ConfigurazioneSpringSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
        // Metodi per la gestione dell'utente autenticato.
        @Autowired
        GestioneUtentiSpringSecurity gestioneUtentiSpringSecurity;
        
        // Metodo per crittografare la password
        @Bean
        public static BCryptPasswordEncoder metodoCrittografia() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
        @Autowired
        public void crittografiaPassword(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(gestioneUtentiSpringSecurity).passwordEncoder(metodoCrittografia());
        }
    
        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;
        // 2) ?????????????
        @Bean
        public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
            JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl db = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
            db.setDataSource(dataSource);
            return db;
        }
        // Se l'utente cambia la password il pulsante "Ricordami" continua a funzionare.
        @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }
    
        // Configurazione di Spring Security.
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // 1) ?????????????
        //http.csrf().disable();
        http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
        //http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository());
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(
                    "/",
                    "/login",
                    "/benvenuto",
                    "/registrazione",
                    "/registrazione-eseguita",
                    "/pagine-applicazione"
            ).permitAll();
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/area-riservata")
                    .access("hasAnyRole('" + livelliDeiRuoli.elencoRuoli(1L) + "')");
            // ... ecc...
            http.authorizeRequests().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/errore-403");
            http.authorizeRequests().and().formLogin()
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/pagina-login")
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    .failureUrl("/login?errore=true")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .and().logout().logoutUrl("/pagina-logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout=true");
    
            // 2) ?????????????
            http.authorizeRequests().and()
                    .rememberMe().tokenRepository(this.persistentTokenRepository())
                    .tokenValiditySeconds(365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
        }
    
    }
```

**B) GestioneUtentiSpringSecurity implements UserDetailsService**

```java
    // 3) ?????????????
    // Creazione utente autenticato.
    @Service
    public class GestioneUtentiSpringSecurity implements UserDetailsService {
    
        @Autowired
        private UtenteRepository utenteRepository;
        @Autowired
        private RuoloRepository ruoloRepository;
        @Autowired
        //...
    
        // Creazione utente autenticato
        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String nomeUtente) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    
            // Si cerca l'utente nel database
            Utente utente = trovaUtenteConPrivilegiDiAutenticazione(nomeUtente);
            if (utente == null) {
                // System.out.println("L'utente " + nomeUtente + " non è stato trovato!");
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("L'utente " + nomeUtente + " non è stato trovato nel database.");
            }
            // Si cercano i ruoli dell'utente
            List<String> ruoliUtente = null;
            try {
                ruoliUtente = this.ruoloRepository.trovaRuoliUtente(utente.getId());
            }catch (Exception b){
                ruoliUtente = null;
            }
    
            // Si caricano in una lista di oggetti GrantedAuthority i ruoli di un dato utente.
            // GrantedAuthority è una classe di Spring Security che contiene i privilegi di un utente.
            List<GrantedAuthority> grantList = null;
            try{
                grantList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
                if (ruoliUtente != null) {
                    for (String ruolo : ruoliUtente) {
                        GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(ruolo);
                        grantList.add(authority);
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception c){
                grantList = null;
            }
    
            // Si crea un oggetto specifico di Spring Security che rappresenta l'utente autenticato. Questo oggetto contiene 3
            // informazioni: nome utente, password e privilegi. Questi ultimi, in questa applicazione si fanno coincidere
            // con i ruoli.
            UserDetails userDetails = null;
            if((utente != null) && (ruoliUtente != null) && (grantList != null)){
                userDetails = (UserDetails) new User(utente.getNome(), utente.getPassword(), grantList);
            }
            return userDetails;
        }
    
        // Si cerca l'utente nel database
        public Utente trovaUtenteConPrivilegiDiAutenticazione(String nomeUtente){
            // ...
        }
    
    }
```

**C) pom.xml**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.5</version>
            <relativePath/> <!--/* cerca genitore dal repository */-->
        </parent>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
        <artifactId>...</artifactId>
        <version>...</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <name>...</name>
        <description>...</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>11</java.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
                <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <finalName>gestioneutenti</finalName>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <packagingExcludes>
                                WEB-INF/classes/it/...
                            </packagingExcludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
    </project>
```

**D) @Controller**

```java
    @Controller
    public class ControlloPagineWeb {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String paginaLogin(
                Model model,
                Principal principal,
                HttpSession session,
                HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response
        ) {
            variabiliGeneraliPerPaginaHTML(principal, model, session, request, response);
            model.addAttribute("titolo", "Login");
            model.addAttribute("messaggio", "Login");
            return "login";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/logout-eseguito", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String logoutEseguitoConSuccesso(
                Model model,
                Principal principal,
                HttpSession session,
                HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response
        ) {
            variabiliGeneraliPerPaginaHTML(principal, model, session, request, response);
            model.addAttribute("titolo", "Login");
            model.addAttribute("messaggio", "Login");
            model.addAttribute("logoutEseguito", "Logout eseguito correttamente.");
            return "login";
        }

    }
```

**E) Sometimes I get this error.**

```
    D:\ALTRO\Java\jdk-11.0.13\bin\java.exe
    ...
    2022-03-29 21:23:09.245 ERROR 20124 --- [.1-8443-exec-10] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Error running socket processor
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HKDF.extract(HKDF.java:93) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HKDF.extract(HKDF.java:119) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ServerHello.setUpPskKD(ServerHello.java:1169) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$T13ServerHelloProducer.produce(ServerHello.java:547) ~[na:na]
    ...
```

**F) Logout button: (/pagina-logout)**

```html
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="dropdown-item" th:if="${#request.userPrincipal != null}"
th:href="@{/pagina-logout}">
<b><i class="bi bi-box-arrow-right"></i> Logout</b>
</a>
</li>
```

**G) Logout button configuration: (/pagina-logout)**

```java
        http.authorizeRequests().and().formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/pagina-login")
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .failureUrl("/login?errore=true")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/pagina-logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout=true");
```

Comment: Let's focus on the problem of not being able to log out. Where does the request to the logout endpoint happen (perhaps an HTML page)? What does it mean that the user is not able to log out, do they get an error or no response?

Comment: Thank you very much for your availability. The endpoint occurs at "/page-logout". I use a button pointing to "/page-logout" I have not mapped "/page-logout" in the controller (ControlloPagineWeb.java) and there is no "page-logout.html" file. Is this a mistake? When I hit the button pointing to "/page-logout" Spring Boot sends me back to the 404.html error page. If I browse the site using the menu I agree that I am still authenticated.

Comment: Do you make a POST request to "/page-logout"? Could you share the page that contains the button pointing to "/page-logout"?

Comment: No I do not perform a POST request to "/pagina-logout" but a GET request. There is no html page associated with "/pagina-logout". There is no @RequestMapping for the "/pagina-logout" resource.
I simply entered "/pagina-logout" in the navigation menu of the site (see point F of the post). I define "/pagina-logout" only in ConfigureSpringSecurity.java (see point G of the post). I understood how I can format the code, it was all written, it was enough to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If CSRF protection is enabled then the request to the logout endpoint configured via `.logoutUrl(...)` must be a POST.

The best way forward is to change the logout button to be:

```html
<li class="nav-item">
    <div class="dropdown-item" th:if="${#request.userPrincipal != null}">
        <form th:action="@{/pagina-logout}" method="post">
            <input id="logout" type="submit" value="Log Out"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Marvelous! Thank you very much for your help! Your code works perfectly.

1) Can I insert the following tag on all the forms of the site or only on the login page?

<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}">

2) Which of the following two solutions is the best and what are the differences?

http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());

http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository());

Comment: Yes, you can insert it on all forms. Check out the Spring Security [reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#servlet-csrf-configure-custom-repository) to learn about `CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())`.